# Changing in model not affected on a view ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I try to add data to model manually like this

```
beforeModel: function() {
    var scope =this;
    Ember.$.getJSON('/restURL').then(function(response){
                    scope.store.pushPayload('consultation',response);
},
```

and data successfully loaded, I can see it in ember debugger, but I have a problem - data is not render on a view.

template in application.hbs:

```
{{#each item in model}}
           {{#link-to 'consultation' item}}{{item.remoteUser.name}}{{/link-to}}
{{/each}}
```

NOTE: when I load data using `this.store.find('consultation');` it's work fine, but I have custom URL and can't use this construction.

Comment: and what is your `model` hook then?

Comment: model hook contain: return this.store.find('consultation'); and in beforeModel I want add additional fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to load consultations using a direct ajax call. The way you are doing it now, the consultations are retrieved in `beforeModel`, then, since you are not returning the promise, Ember immediately proceeds to execute the `model` hook *before* the ajax calls completes. The `this.store.find` you have in the model hook is likely to make another, possibly invalid request to the server. The easiest way is simply

```
model: function() {
  var store = this.store;

  return Ember.$.getJSON('/restURL')
    .then(function(response) {
      store.pushPayload('consultation', response);
      return store.all('consultation');
    });
}
```

Note the use of `store.all`, which is a dynamic collection of all objects of that type already in the store.

You could also consider breaking the logic into `beforeModel` and `model` as in:

```
beforeModel: function() {
  return Ember.$.getJSON('/restURL')
    // this binding style is a matter of personal preference :-)
    .then(this.store.pushPayload.bind(this.store, 'consultation'))
},

model: function() {
  return this.store.all('consultation');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, torazaburo. It's work. I added this hook to my Application route.
Also I have Records model and after loading consultation by URL via Ajax I need to choose this consultation and show records of it. Do I need add some hook in Consultation route?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `afterModel` hook instead of `beforeModel`, because `beforeModel` is not use for data aggregation. `beforeModel` occurs before the model try to get resolved, it can not access the resolved model, so you can't rely on it to add extra data to model.

On the other hand, `afterModel` hook will pass the resolved model in as the first argument, so you can further decorate the model as your needs, and you can return a promise just like the `model` hook.

Take look this simple example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nukebe/1

Comment: In my case resolvedModel doesn't have push and pushPayload methods. I got message:
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'pushPayload'